# Compare two files strictly line-by-line, without insertions or deletions

Tags: command-line, diff, file-comparison

I have two files that essentially contain a memory dumps in a hex format. At the moment I use diff to see if the files are different and where the differences are. However, this can be misleading when trying to determine the exact location (i.e. memory address) of the difference. Consider the following example showing the two files side-by-side.

```
file1:       file2:

0001    |    0001
ABCD    |    FFFF
1234    |    ABCD
FFFF    |    1234
```

Now `diff -u` will show one insertion and one deletion, although 3 lines (memory locations) have changed between the two files:

```
 0001
+FFFF
 ABCD
 1234
-FFFF
```

Is there an easy way to compare the two files such that each line is only compared with the same line (in terms of line numbering) in the other file? So in this example it should report that the last 3 lines have changed, along with the changed lines from `file1` and `file2`. The output doen't have to be diff-style, but it would be cool if it could be colored (at the moment I color the `diff -u` output using `sed` so that could easily be adapted).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This could be an approach:

```
diff <(nl file1) <(nl file2)
```

With `nl` number the lines that `diff` recognizes the lines line by line.

Comment: That's cool, I didn't know the nl program. Those unix tools are really handy, but there are _so many_ of them.

Comment: I just tried this, and unfortunately what I get is: every line of the first file, followed by every line of the second file... instead of line 1 from file 1, followed by line 1 from file two, followed by line 2 from file one, followed by line 2 from file 2...

Comment: @MichaelHewson It sounds like your two files have no lines in common. In that case, that's just how `diff` works. You might try the gui program `meld` which shows the two files side by side. As in `meld <(nl file1) <(nl file2)`

Comment: Amazing solution.

Comment: nl by default only numbers non-empty lines, hence this solution doesn't work as intended when files have empty lines in between non-empty lines. A better alternative is: ```diff <(nl -ba file1) <(nl -ba file2)```.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't work for me anymore. Maybe it's file dependent

Comment: @MichaelHewson I found that if I entered a newline after each line before doing the diff, I got what I needed, since it would see the numbered lines differing but the space lines the same

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from the meld answer this works for me at the command line `sort -n -k1,1 -s <(nl file1) <(nl file2)`. Useful where meld isn't installed.