# comparing two files line by line

Tags: shell-script

I have got two files of same numer of lines in each.

1.txt

```
1,2,1,1
1,2,2,1
1,2,4,2
1,2,1,2
```

2.txt

```
1,2,1,2
1,2,2,1
1,2,4,1
1,2,1,1
```

Now I want to compare them line by line, first line with first line, second with second and so on and print those lines in the first file (1.txt) which are not matching with the corresponding lines in the secon file (2.txt).

In this scenario the output will be:

```
1,2,1,1
1,2,4,2
1,2,1,2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}(!($0 in a)){print}' file2 file1
```

`NR==FNR{a[$0];next}` :
For the first file (file2) create an array `a`, with key `$0` = whole line , and go to the next line. NR is the global record number of awk and FNR is the current file record number. The condition NR==FNR will be valid only for the first file read (file2)

`(!($0 in a){print}`:
When the first file2 finishes, then read file1 and if the whole line `$0` of file1 does not belong in the keys of array `a` print this line.

With grep:

```
grep -vxF -f file2 file1
```

`-v` : catch the non matching lines
`-x` : match the whole line
`-F` : make a fixed match instead of pattern match
`-f` : use file2 to load patterns

**For the updated data** in order to perform a line by line comparison you can use awk and not grep :

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0;next}$0!=a[FNR]{print}' file2 file1
1,2,1,1
1,2,4,2
1,2,1,2
```

Obviously, both files should have the same number of lines.

Comment: I went with the second one, using grep and it helped, thank you.

Comment: @SayanSikder grep is all times classic, but my favorite one is awk.

Comment: @SayanSikder Since comments are hard to read i propose to include those new lines in your main question (press edit just bellow your existing question)

Comment: I have changed the sample inputs, and accordingly the output in the main question. I wanted line to line comparison, each line should match the corresponding lines only of the other file, not just any line of it.

Comment: @SayanSikder See update. Ony awk (or similar advanced text processing language) seems able for this task. `grep` and probably `comm`,`join`,`diff` i doubt that can match your updated requirement.

Comment: I think it serves the purpose, thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Simple `comm` (compare two sorted files line by line) approach:

```
comm -2 -3 1.txt 2.txt
```

The output:

```
1,2,1,2
1,2,3,3
```

---

- `-2` - suppress column `2` (lines unique to `FILE2`)
- `-3` - suppress column `3` (lines that appear in both files)

---

If input files are unsorted use the following:

```
comm -2 -3 <(sort 1.txt) <(sort 2.txt)
```

### ----------

The alternative solution using `diff` tool with `--LTYPE-line-format=LFMT` options:

```
diff --unchanged-line-format="" --old-line-format="%L" --new-line-format="" 1.txt 2.txt
```

- `--unchanged-line-format=""` - eliminate printing common lines
- `--new-line-format=""` - eliminate printing lines from the 2nd file
- `--old-line-format="%L"` - output the crucial lines from the 1st file

Answer (score 1):

Just simply use diff command:

```
 diff --suppress-common-lines -n file1 file2
```

For your example files output will look like this:

```
>diff file1 file2
2,3c2,3
< 1,2,1,2
< 1,2,3,3
---
> 1,2,1,1
> 1,2,3,1
```

< indicates lines from file1,

> indicated lines from file2,

= indicated lines common for both files

Answer (score 1):

I had essentially the same problem (except that I wanted to print both lines when they are different, not just the lines in file 1). I found a great solution on [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136380/compare-two-files-strictly-line-by-line-without-insertions-or-deletions?rq=1).

```
wdiff <(nl file1) <(nl file2)
```

Sample output:

```
...
77  true
78  false
79  [-true-]        {+false+}
80  [-true-]        {+false+}
...
```

Here we use the tool `nl` to number the lines of both files first, so that `diff` or `wdiff` pairs them up by number. You can then use the various options for `diff` and `wdiff` to tune the output as desired.