# comm is not proving expected result

Tags: text-processing, file-comparison, comm

I have couple of files (*file 1.txt* and *file2.txt*) and I am using unix "comm" command to compare those files to find out unique lines on file1.txt

**Here are the lines having on file1.txt:**

```
OD1
EN2
OD3
OD4
OD5
EN6
EN7
EN8
EN9
OD10
OD11
OD12
```

**Here are the lines having on file2.txt:**

```
EN1
EN2
EN3
OD4
OD5
EN6
EN7
EN8
EN9
OD10
```

I am using the command as :

```
comm -23 file1.txt file2.txt
```

### actual

The result is:

```
OD1 
OD10
OD11
OD12
OD3
```

### expecting

I was expecting:

```
OD1 
OD11
OD12
OD3
```

Can you please help how to get the expected results?

Comment: I get `...   OD5
comm: file 2 is not in sorted order
  EN6 ...` (this is taken from the right-most column).  "comm - compare two sorted files line by line".

Comment: Check also this topic: [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377659/comparing-two-files-line-by-line)

Comment: `comm` expects the file to be sorted before inputting. Looks like both of your files are not sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files have to be sorted lexically or `comm` will not work.

Sort them into order and try again.

Or use:

```
comm -23 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However I still I am getting the result where OD10 is getting included. Here is my test result:OD1
OD10
OD11
OD12
OD3

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
sdiff -s file1.txt file2.txt | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u
```

Output is

```
OD1                                                                                                                                                                      
OD11                                                                                                                                                                     
OD12                                                                                                                                                                     
OD3
```

Comment: I tried the same command but getting result with OD10 included on the list. here are the result :OD1
OD10
OD11
OD12
OD3

Comment: Can you check data correctly?  I have used the same data which you provided in the question and got the output shown.

Comment: It is surprising! With the same data I am getting different result. Any idea does that depend on linux version? The one I am running is on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7

Comment: Probably there are some additional characters in OD10. open the file in vi. then enter :set list

Comment: Thanks! It is working fine now with the new data set. Even the first command suggested works well now!